# Array assign in smarty

Tags: php, oop, smarty3

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => willt
            [username] => willt
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => Adam 
            [username] => adamb
        )
)
```

I have an array and am assigning it to smarty via `$smarty->assign('array', $array);`, but I can't get it in the template. How to correctly refer to it? I tried:

```
array[1].name
array.1.name
```

with and without `$`.

Comment: {$array[1]['name']} should work (i think).

Comment: @Nile I think so too, but i am catching Exception: Syntax Error in template "./templates/index.tpl" on line 3 "

Comment: can you show me the contents of both files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it visible in the template? If it is, `{$array.1.name}` should do it.

You could also check the [documentation](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.variables.tpl#language.variables.assoc.arrays).